# Convert String to Type in Java

Tags: java

I've got a class:

```
public Account(String name, String passwd)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.passwd = passwd;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public String getPasswd()
{
    return passwd;
}

private String name;
private String passwd;
```

And I've got this class as well:

```
public class CreateAccountAction implements ActionListener
{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
    {
        Account newAccount = new Account(GameGUI.textField.getText(), GameGUI.passwordField.getText());
        Logger.send("You have created an account with the username, "+newAccount.getName()+".");
    }
}
```

Now, I have one more class:

```
public class LogInAction implements ActionListener
{   
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
    {
        String name = GameGUI.textField.getText();
        if(GameGUI.passwordField.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(name.getPasswd()))
        {
            Logger.send("You have logged in.");
            loggedIn = true;
        }
        else
            {
            Logger.send("Incorrect password.");
        }
    }   

    public boolean loggedIn()
    {
        return this.loggedIn;
    }

    private boolean loggedIn = false;
}
```

So. In the third class, I'm trying to use the `name.getPasswd()` function in the first class. However, name is a string. But I need to refer to the Object with the name of the string itself. I created an `Account leviathan = new Account("Leviathan", "password")`. And the `name` String contains `leviathan`. How to I convert that String's contents into the Account, leviathan?

Comment: Hi I think you mistake what you can do. 
name.getPasswd() will never work because name is declared as a String not as an Account so you can't ask for the method getPasswd() on this.

Answer (score 0):

like I told you before you made a mistake in your vision of the program.
Actually you want to do

```
    String name = GameGUI.textField.getText();
    if(GameGUI.passwordField.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(name.getPasswd()))
```

But this can't work because name is declared as a String not as an Account so you can't ask for the method getPasswd() on this.

To correct that you can try to make a method in LogInAction  for example like this

```
   public Account getAccountFromName(String name)
   {
     // your code to get the account
   }
```

and your code will change in

```
    String name = GameGUI.textField.getText();
    Account acc = getAccountFromName(name);
    if(GameGUI.passwordField.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(acc.getPasswd()))
```

But for all of this you will have to have an arrayList of existing account for example.
For that you have to change your code in CreateAccountAction. You will need to add for example an accList and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to achieve what you are trying to do.  You will need to create a service that stores and retrieves accounts from some data source.  Then you can call that service and load the account you are looking for by name.

Would kinda look like this:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
{
    AccountService accountService = new AccountService();
    Account account = accountService.getAccountByName(GameGUI.textField.getText());

    if (account == null) {
        Logger.send("Account name does not exist.");
    } else {
        if(GameGUI.passwordField.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(account.getPasswd()))
        {
            Logger.send("You have logged in.");
            loggedIn = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Logger.send("Incorrect password.");
        }
    }
}
```

Also, as a tip, when storing login credentials use a hashing algorithm.  This will protect the passwords while they are in the data source.  When a user logs in, simply hash the password they attempted to log in with and then compare that to the already hashed password you have stored in your data source.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve what you want. You've made it harder on yourself, by putting each actionlistener in its own class.

You never save the "newAccount" variable anywhere, so it only exists until the end of your actionPerformed. To handle any kind of data using a GUI, you should consider creating a new class, and call it Controller, and keep the data in there. You could then have an ArrayList as a variable in the controller, which is a list of currently known users (a list of Account-objects). Let's call it accountList.

This Control class then has the following methods:

```
public static Account getAccountByName(String name){
// do some looping to find the account
}
public static boolean checkIfNameAlreadyExists(){
// make for-loop to check if name is in use
}
public static void addAccount(String name, String passwd){
    accountList.add(new Account(name, passwd));
}
```

[Make Control a singleton](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0425-designpatterns.html), and have the constructor create a new ArrayList accountList (or possibly load them from a file?) upon creation. Then all your classes can access these methods, by calling Control.addAccount(bla1, bla2) or Control.getAccountByName("John Prescott").
The points mentioned by Joe about the hashing of the passwords, is of course also valid here.